# What is the <Primary> modifier key?

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to use gnome-tweaks to learn more key bindings and assign new ones.  The most extensive list of assignable actions seems to be provided by gnome-tweaks, under Settings Editor, row xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.

As shown on the screenshot, many such bindings involve a  modifier key.  What does that map to in physical keyboards?  For concreteness, mine is a ThinkPad keyboard with bottom row of keys Fn, Ctrl, Alt, AltGr and of course Shift.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and the window manager is xubuntu-desktop.[image: dialog under gnome-tweaks]

Answer (score 1):

It's typically the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. The `<Primary>` label exists so that GTK can have  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-based shortcuts for Linux/Windows and  <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd>-based shortcuts in macOS. See [this U&L post for details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168505/what-is-primary-for-a-key).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I searched for "Primary" with other terms such as "key" etc and got only answers where "primary" had some irrelevant meaning.